# Web audio player that can link to a certain time in audio?

Tags: audio

I post weekly podcast shows that are about an hour long onto my Wordpress-powered website. Normally I give an overview (a table of contents of sorts) on each episode post. I want to be able to link to a certain time in an audio file using Javascript and/or Flash, so the table of contents is interactive.

e.g., [a href="#time=4200"]Click here to go to minute 42 in the podcast.[/a]

I haven't found any audio players that include this functionality... Does anyone know of a web audio players that features linking to times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you won't get an answer to this question here. The community on this site could help you to program an audio player doing that, but not point at a player that does it. You should try on another forum, not here.

Answer (score 0):

If your comfortable doing javascript programming, you could use [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS).

Hope that helps.